# How to replace the base Java image in public base image with customized version

Tags: java, docker, redhat, amq, maven-jib

We are using base image of RedHat AMQ `registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-amq-6/amq63-openshift` which is a public base we cannot change. We use that image in jib maven plugin and did some changes to create an app.

However, the security department requires an update to the JDK it uses. We have another image with these fixes included, let's say `company.com/java-with-fix`.

How to make my RedHat AMQ based APP to use that company JDK base image, and in Jib?

Comment: Can I assume your company's JDK is installed in a different directory than the one in registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-amq-6/amq63-openshift? I'm not familiar with RedHat AMQ. Would you share the URL of its Dockerfile?

Comment: The thing is, there is some script to upgrade the base image of RedHat AMQ image to 6.3, by downloading this Openshift template file and do things to it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jboss-openshift/application-templates/master/amq/amq63-persistent.json  this file uses v 1.4.17(what version is this???), and team claim that if this file does not upgrade to higher version, we cannot do anything about it(already being the latest). I see latest of registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-amq-6/amq63-openshift(1.4-44.1634742282) already has java 1.8.0_312, but don't understand the relationship between

Comment: Personally I don't think the 1.4.17 IS the 1.4-17 of amq63-openshift, as there is no version 1.4-17 [here](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/jboss-amq-6/amq63-openshift/595de0f4e69ceb159b35a49e). I don't know how to interpret Openshift template file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JSON file "amq63-persistent.json". I was expecting there's some a startup script that run "java ..." and you just override the JDK location.

Do you specify "container.entrypoint" variable? (reference: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#extended-usage)

Comment: Thanks for helping. Found some ways through a premade script; basically the script will find the latest version at https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/jboss-amq-6/amq63-openshift/tags/list, pull it, tag and upload to our internal repo as a base; the application is based on this internal base, and when it's with Java 1.8.0_312, the app is fine. So it's basically solved.